# Any example of using SVG bultin library?

Tags: graphics

I heard that you could draw SVG in emacs using the `svg.el` library, but while i managed to get the right dependencies (I'm on ubuntu 19.10) and while compiling the latest version from the savannah.gnu repo work great, i couldn't see anything related to svg (`svg.el`) being used.(that is, i couldn't find it using `M-x`)

Though, from what i seen, it does work as i managed to install `svg-clock` but, nothing else show up in the `M-x` prompt about svg...

And yes, i also added `imagemagick` support to emacs, but no dice.

Additional details: I'm also using `lucid` instead of the gtk gui. Here the full configure flags i used `./configure --with-x-toolkit=lucid --with-xml2 --with-xft --with-libotf --with-imagemagick --with-rsvg`

Basically i want either examples of how to use the `svg.el` (mostly so i can check if it's actually being used, or to check if it wasn't meant to be launched using `M-x`)

Lastly, i did used `(image-type-available-p 'svg)` to check whether it was available or not, and it was indeed...it just didn't appear in the prompt of `M-x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SVG library is a library for programmatic generation of SVG images.  Check out the source code of svg-clock.el for an example of how to use it: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/elpa.git/tree/packages/svg-clock/svg-clock.el

Here's a simplified example you can evaluate in the scratch buffer:

```
(require 'svg)

(let ((buffer "*svg-test*")
      (width 200)
      (height 100))
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create buffer)
    (let (buffer-read-only)
      (erase-buffer)
      (let ((svg (svg-create width height)))
        (svg-gradient svg "bg" 'linear '((0 . "#000") (100 . "#fff")))
        (svg-rectangle svg 0 0 width height :gradient "bg")
        (svg-insert-image svg))
      (special-mode)))
  (display-buffer buffer))
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought of doing this!